# Error with document.getElementById: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, syntax-error

I get the following error ***"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"*** and anything that I tried solve the issue. I taking an online course and this is part of my final project but I stuck without get any solution, please explain me how to solve this and why this happen to my code, thanks and here are my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My form</title>
</head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function register() {
    var x = new Array();
    x[0] = document.getElementById('name').value;
    x[1] = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    x[2] = document.getElementById('email').value;
    x[3] = document.getElementById('password').value;
    x[4] = document.getElementById('cpassword').value;

    var h = new Array();
    h[0] = "<span style='color:red'>Please type your name!</span>";
    h[1] = "<span style='color:red'>Please type your last name!</span>";
    h[2] = "<span style='color:red'>Please type your email!</span>";
    h[3] = "<span style='color:red'>Please type your password!</span>";
    h[4] = "<span style='color:red'>Please confirm your password</span>";

    var divs = new Array("mname", "mlname", "memail", "mpassword", "mcpassword");

    for (i in x) {

        var error = h[i];
        var div = divs[i];

        if (x[i]=="") {
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = error;
        }else{
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "OK!";
        }
    }
}

function pass() {

    var first = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var second = document.getElemntById('cpassword').value;

    if (second == first) {
        document.getElementById('mcpassword').innerHTML = "OK!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('mcpassword').innerHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Your password don't match!</span>";
    }
}
</script>
<body>
    <form>
        <table border="1">
                <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" onkeyup="register()"/></td><td><div id="mname"></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" onkeyup="register()"/></td><td><div id="mlname"></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name= "email" id="email" onkeyup="register()"/></td><td><div id="memail"></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" onkeyup="register()"/></td><td><div id="mpassword"></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Confirm Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" onkeyup="pass()"/></td><td><div id="mcpassword"></div></td></tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe this line? `var second = document.getElemntById('cpassword').value;`

Comment: When posting code, it *really* helps if you let us know what line # the error happens at.  Not just the line in the error message, but the affected line in the code you post.

Comment: Thanks!!! vch save my date today. Jeremy, I'm going to following your advice for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the error

You are saying

```
var second = document.getElemntById('cpassword').value;
```

it should be

```
var second = document.getElementById('cpassword').value;
```